# How to display multiple fields in jQuery autocomplete and upon selecting a result only one field should be visible in the textbox?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a table which has several fields: **Item**, **Quantity** and so on. I want the autocomplete search results to display the format "**Item - Quantity**", but upon selecting the result, it should call only **Item** into the text box.

How do I achieve this? Could you please guide me. I am an amateur coder and do not know jQuery. I copied a code online, which is given below. It displays only the **Item** field.

The Java script code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Item").autocomplete({
        source:'Con_GetItemNames.php',
        maxLength:5
    });
});
</script>
```

The Con_GetItemNames.php is:

```
$term=$_GET["term"];

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM StationeryConsumables.TotalStock 
                    WHERE Item like '%".$term."%' ORDER BY Item");

$json=array();

while($totalstock=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $json[]=array('value'=>$totalstock["Item"], 'label'=>$totalstock["Item"]);    
    }
echo json_encode($json);
```

Thanks,
Deepak

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I do not know jQuery as such, but by tweaking the code, I was able to get the job done.

Here goes the Con_GetItemNames.php code:

```
$term=$_GET["term"];

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM StationeryConsumables.TotalStock 
                    WHERE Item like '%".$term."%' ORDER BY Item");

$json=array();

while($totalstock=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $json[]=array('value'=>$totalstock["Item"], 
                  'label'=>$totalstock["Item"]. " Quantity: ". $totalstock["Quantity"]);    
    }
echo json_encode($json);
```